# jQuery .load when complete fade in and remove loading spinner

Tags: jquery, load

I am using jQuery .load function to get 3 list items from other page. It is working perfectly, but I was wondering how to add "loading spinner" while content is loading and how to fade in my content, when it is loaded.

My code :

```
$('.homeProducts').load('http://localhost/products #product_list li:lt(3)');
```

P.S I don't know it is the right way to get those products, but it works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best was is using the global `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` events:

```
$('#yourSpinner').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

The `ajaxStart` event will fire when the number of pending ajax requests raises from 0 to 1 and the `ajaxStop` event will fire when all ajax requests have finished.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
$("#content").html('<div align="center"><img style="margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;"
align="center" src="ajax-loader.gif"></div>');              
setTimeout('do()', n); 

 ...    
function do(){
$("#content").load('http://localhost/products #product_list li:lt(3)',{},function(){
$(this).fadeIn();
});                                                     
}
```

Where *n* is the ammount of time after wich the function will be fired. So the spinner is shown for at least *n* milliseconds.